# Value error when I scrape the web: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created my function which scrapes some tables from the web and save it in a csv but I don't know why is not working.

Below is the code I have tried:

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def record (part) :

        url="http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/res20130914/{}".format(part)
        u=urllib2.urlopen(url)
        try:
            html=u.read()
        finally:
            u.close()
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
        c=[]
        for n in soup.find_all('center'):
            for b in n.find_all('a')[2:]:
                c.append(b.text)

        t=(len(c)-2)/2        

            with open('name.csv', 'wb') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)

        for i in range(t):
            url = "http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/res20130914/A/011/{}.html".format(i)
            u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        try:
            html = u.read()
        finally:
            u.close()
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
        for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            row = [elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds[:4]]
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Then, I run my function:

```
record("A/041/0.html")
```

The output is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-cfa187b69dc4> in <module>()
     37             writer.writerow(row)
     38 
---> 39 record("A/041/0.html")
     40 
     41 

<ipython-input-119-cfa187b69dc4> in record(part)
     35             tds = tr.find_all('td')
     36             row = [elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds[:4]]
---> 37             writer.writerow(row)
     38 
     39 record("A/041/0.html")

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

What the function should do is just, scrap the tables in [this](http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/res20130914/A/041/0.html) direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made indentation error on your code `with open('name.csv', 'wb') as f:`

And try to change `writerow` mechanism into `with` statement.

You can try

```
with open('name.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for i in range(t):
        url = "http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/res20130914/A/011/{}.html".format(i)
        u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    try:
        html = u.read()
    finally:
        u.close()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds[:4]]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

The above code are working fine for me. And the result stored as `name.csv` on my machine.
Output is like

```
455576,"ASTONITAS BELLO, ERIK JAVIER",011,1454.1250
468012,"ASTORNE RAMÍREZ, SERGIO MIGUEL",011, 
486188,"ATALAYA CARPIO, MELANY LESLIE",011,639.3000
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is a giveaway here:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

The file you're attempting to write to has not been opened. Looking through your code,

```
with open('name.csv', 'wb') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)

writer.writerow(row)
```

It's a bit unclear, are you trying to output to name.csv?

You might want to review your syntax / file processes in these lines..

Comment: name is the csv name of the file I want to create.